# Why is the _id for a mongo document STRING but not ObjectID by default

Tags: mongodb, meteor, objectid

[The document of Meteor](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection) says that it use STRING as the _id by default. What's the meaning behind it? What if I write a script to import a huge csv file but would like to give each of them a random string, what can I do?

Comment: It just means that the IDs will be random strings by default. Your script can just insert each record, and they will have random string IDs automatically generated.

Comment: But my script is written in python. And it doesn't support to insert a document with random _id by default. Need I implement it by my self?

Comment: In that case the records should have mongo generated ObjectIDs and you can specify to use `MONGO` generation in your JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Seems it's better that I set it as a MONGO-style _id. But I'm still curious about why they use the random string by default

Comment: I believe it's mainly for convenience. Strings can be more easily used directly in URLs and HTML without having to call `new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID()` or `doc._id.toHexString()`. Also, strings can be compared directly with the `===` operator rather than using `EJSON.equals()`. Note that Meteor's timestamps in its `ObjectID`s are not useful, so if you want timestamps you should add them in your deny rules or use [a package like `collection-hooks`](https://atmospherejs.com/package/collection-hooks)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's been [quite a bit of discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-talk/f-ljBdZOwPk/oQYZQxCAKN8J) about why Meteor uses string IDs instead of ObjectIDs, but it basically boils down to the fact that generating ObjectIDs is a lot harder on the client.

The string id generation is implemented as [`Random.id()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#random) in Meteor. So if you're importing the CSV in Javascript in a Meteor process, just use that.